# asterisk PAMI Originate Call issue

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

Received an unknown call with DID

> [rawContent:protected] =>
>
> Event: Newexten
>       Privilege: call,all
>       Channel: SIP/701-000056ff
>       ChannelState: 6
>       ChannelStateDesc: Up
>       CallerIDNum: 701
>       CallerIDName: 701
>       ConnectedLineNum: 
>       ConnectedLineName: 
>       Language: en
>       AccountCode: 
>       Context: from-digital
>       Exten: xxxxxx
>       Priority: 2
>       Uniqueid: 1483958245.105223
>       Linkedid: 1483958245.105223
>       Extension: xxxxxx
>       Application: NoOp
>       AppData: Received an unknown call with DID set to xxxxx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Acordinly to this fragment call origination was successfull, your dialplan for context from-digital have application Noop with that message

That message is from your dialplan and have no any relation to asterisk internals.

Comment: I have remove the outbound rules and set DID to any but now when I originate call from PAMI it doesn't give that error but it hangup

Comment: Debug is offtopic on SO. No other answer on your question possible.